# To make it available on the App Store, accept the terms of the latest agreement in Agreements, Tax, and Banking

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is a question relating to releasing software on the Apple iTunesConnect interface. This past month (March 2015). Apple's software is very finicky and new problems come up often and are short lived.

I have received this message when attempting to "Submit for Review" my app:

> Your app can't be made available on the App Store. To make it available on the App Store, accept the terms of the latest agreement in Agreements, Tax, and Banking.

[image]

Clicking on that link produces this page, and none of the links there lead to something related to "[accepting] the terms of the latest agreement". Also, I am the sole user with access to this system, and I have the "legal admin" permissions.

[image]

How do I get past this?

Comment: Going to https://developer.apple.com, logging into your account and accept the new terms should fix this. They recently updated the terms which you have to accept in  order to submit new Apps. But there should also be a notice on iTunes Connect that you have to do this

Comment: Same thing for me.. have no idea what to do.. There is nothing to accept, or something to do..

Comment: This is fixed now for me, answered below with image.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO is the best place for these short-lived problem, but SO should be the one-stop for all developers so what you gonna do?

Comment: Ahh, fixed for me too by requesting new contract..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't see `Request Amendments` section, login to https://developer.apple.com and make sure you have agreed with iOS terms and conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to press the Request button under Request Amendments for iOS Paid Applications. It's in the middle of the screen, not the bottom. That's what they're looking for. It's very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I returned to this page later today and this is what appeared:

[image]

This allowed me to complete the workflow

Comment: Can you give specific steps like, clicked on Request button, then clicked on Done button etc. etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have legal role for this. If you are just an admin you can not request and accept the agreement, All you can do is view the agreement. Once you sign in with a legal role, you can request (see the Request button) the agreement and accept it.